# Can we regularly update same snapshot & also the VM created from this snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS instance say DB-Instance created from a snapshot of another Aws instance (snapshot->Image->AWS Instance) . Is it possible update this same snapshot regularly with something like incremental updates and thereby also dynamically updating my AWS DB-Instance with new changes since it was created from this snapshot previously.

Comment: Is this an RDS instance or an EC2 instance you've installed a database on? RDS has built in backups. If it's EC2 what you want is EC2 snapshots, which you can automate with [lifecycle manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-lifecycle-management-for-amazon-ebs-snapshots/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can update the running instance from a new volume snapshot. It may be possible with some custom tools that could figure out the difference between the old and new but I'm not aware of any such tool.

---

However you can try to approach it from a *kind-of-immutable-infrastructure* perspective:

1. Create your instance from the snapshot with 2 EBS volumes:

   - *First* being the configured root / OS volume. Never do any important changes on this volume.
   - *Second* being the data volume (e.g. DB data)
2. When a new Snapshot/AMI is available replace the instance with a new one built from the *new root/OS volume* and *old data volume* detached from the original instance.

   Or have the data on some other storage, like EFS.

You can even automate it through *Auto Scaling Group* - rolling over the instance whenever the ASG is updated with a new AMI.

That's probably the closest and cleanest you can get.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot incrementally transfer a snapshot delta using AWS' built-in features. You can clone it, throw away the old clone, and mount the new one, if you only ever write to one instance.

If you need data to be synchronously available on both instances, the you have three options:

1) Use one volume mounted on both instances. You will need a cluster file system to simultaneously mount read-write in both sides, for example GFS2.

2) Similar to 1), but instead of mounting a shared volume between the nodes, use DRBD to synchronously replicate data at block level between the two nodes.

3) GlusterFS.

If asynchronous replication is sufficient for your requirements, you have two options:

1) lsyncd

2) ZFS with periodic snapshots and incremental transfers. Note that this requires secondary nodes to be read-only. This is probably the closest solution to what you described in your question.